# Java. Replace relative Links to absolute with regex

Tags: java, regex

I want to replace in a String, which represents a Html-File,all relative Links with absolute Links. I write the following method, which does not work. any links are followed by a duplicate baseurl like http://www.google.dehttp://www.google.de/resource?

```
    public static String replacePattern(URL targetUrl,String urlAsString,String patternString) throws IOException{
    System.out.println(targetUrl.toString());
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(urlAsString);

    Set<String> replacedStrings = new TreeSet<String>();


    //return matcher.replaceAll(targetUrl.toString()+"$0");

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String relativeLink = matcher.group(1);
        //System.out.println("Find Link " + relativeLink);
        if(!replacedStrings.contains(relativeLink)){
            //System.out.println("Relative Link " + relativeLink);
            String newLink = targetUrl.toString() + relativeLink;
            //System.out.println("New Link " + newLink);
            urlAsString = urlAsString.replace(relativeLink,newLink);
            replacedStrings.add(relativeLink);

        }

    }

    return urlAsString;

}
```

UrlAsString is a String which contains the wholecontent as a String.My patterns are

```
href=['\"](/[^'\"]+)['\"]
```

and

```
src=['\"](/[^'\"]+)['\"]
```

Comment: If you could tell us specifically *what* doesn't work, we might be able to help.

Comment: It would be helpful if could share some relative URLs and expected absolute URLs.

Comment: [Use an XML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/647772)

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Class URL**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html):

```
URL baseUrl = new URL("http://www.domain.com/folder/");
URL url = new URL(baseURL , "url.html");
```

Comment: @AcdcRocknRoll - Did you click on the above link "Class URL" ?